# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error - INSTR Function Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Using INSTR function in a stored procedure . 
INSTR(a,b) in which a is very huge . 
While finding the occurrence of b in a , it results in a big value more than an integer . So i am getting the below error ,

"ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error" .

Can someone help me fix this issue or if i can use some other similar functions in oracle , please write here.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "sample" ( dest_schema IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
digit NUMBER(20);
parentList CLOB;
product NUMBER(38);
digit := INSTR(parentList,product); --> issue comes here
END;
```

Comment: Show us the complete code

Comment: How did you determine that the error was caused by the value being too big? The value returned is of `NUMBER` datatype, so what does this have to do with "integer"? And the max value of `NUMBER` is of the order of 10^38 - I doubt you have a string THAT long.

Comment: You edited to add your code, but are you sure you posted the right code? I believe this will not even compile

Comment: You are missing `BEGIN`. Is this indeed the complete code?

Comment: Yes , my parentList is long string . But I am not sure whether the error comes because of the return value or something else . 
Other than the return value , i do not see any reasons for this error

Comment: Have a look at [DBMS_LOB.INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/DBMS_LOB.htm#GUID-5A3CD712-B28B-4A44-AC96-6DACF7991316)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DBMS_LOB.INSTR`to search a clob. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i998546) for documentation.

```
DBMS_LOB.INSTR (
   lob_loc    IN   CLOB      CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,
   pattern    IN   VARCHAR2  CHARACTER SET lob_loc%CHARSET,
   offset     IN   INTEGER := 1,
   nth        IN   INTEGER := 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted `product` has not been assigned a value, and is thus NULL when `INSTR` is called.